# Prolog : return variable, check if variable is of certain type?

Tags: prolog

I am new to Prolog and can't understand predicates very well. 
First question: How can I 'return' a certain variable? 
We have `alternate(?A, ?B)`. `alternate(first, second)` should give me back `second`, and `alternate(second, first)` should give back `first`.

Second question: How to check if variable is of certain type?
I have for example `ispair(?Pair)`. I have to check if `Pair` is `pos(X,Y)`.

Comment: Predicates are relations (only true or false). If you want to have a result, it must go into the arguments. E.g. `sum(A,B,Result)` would be a predicate with three arguments claiming that A + B = Result holds.

Comment: Note that variables must begin with a capital letter (or `_` if anonymous). If you have a variable, `Pair` and want to query whether it matches (can be unified with) a term, you use the unification operator,`=/2`: so `Pair = pos(X,Y)` will succeed if matches and `X` and `Y` will be instantiated accordingly. Try examples at a Prolog prompt to learn how it works.

Comment: To understand Prolog, make sure you **don't** think of it some kind of weird imperative language. It's a very different beast - it's a declarative language. Understanding that different paradigm is hard but very rewarding. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if that's what you meant, but what about the following:

```
alternate(first, pair(X,_), X).
alternate(second, pair(_,X), X).
```

If you query without any restrictions, you get the following two answer substitutions:

```
?- alternate(X,Y,Z).
X = first,
Y = pair(Z, _5844) ; % hit ; to get the second answer
X = second,
Y = pair(_5842, Z). % variables _12345 are fresh ones created by prolog
```

You can also ask: on which side of the pair (a,b) is b?

```
?- alternate(Where, pair(a,b), b).
Where = second.
```

In the case that your pair is (b,b), you get two solutions:

```
?- alternate(Where, pair(b,b), b).
Where = first ;
Where = second.
```

Also, c is not part of the pair (a,b):

```
?- alternate(Where, pair(a,b), c).
false.
```

If you insist on picking an element from heaven, you will get no as answer:

```
?- alternate(heaven, X, Y).
false.
```

When you know that the first element of a pair is a, prolog will tell you how the pair must look like:

```
?- alternate(first, X, a).
X = pair(a, _5680).
```

Again we have a fresh variable (_5680) in there, because any second term is fine.